# Huge problems with reading in movie frames with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, video, image-processing, crop

I've been working on a project that reads in video frames, stores them in an array and then performs operations on them. The frames are each split into 6 subsections that I have to analyze individually.I had previously been cropping the video beforehand and then was loading it in. I now have the program allow the user to load in the whole movie and then crop each 6th themselves and then the program runs consecutively on each 6th. The problem is that matlab just crashes when loading this now 6-times more pixel dense video in (It's about 120k frames). assuming I can get the user to specify the 6 cropping areas before, is there anyway to load in only a specific area of the movie at a time? Rather than storing the whole frame, only store a 6th? (Unlike how I currently store the whole and THEN crop out a 6th, just store a 6th right off the bat).

Comment: Not sure what you are doing, but storing 120k frames in memory is not a good idea, regardless of storing 1/6th or the full video. You should think about loading the frames one by one or in small batches and then process them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VideoReader does not allow you to load in part of a frame into memory. However, it allows you to load in only certain frames from the video into MATLAB instead of loading in the entire video. Agree with sam that loading in 120K frames of video into MATLAB is a very bad idea. Consider using the READ syntax that allows you to specify the start and stop frames to only read in the video in chunks after which you can use array indexing to slice each frame into 6 portions.

Dinesh